# Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host

Tags: android, android-emulator, avd-manager

When I run `emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_29` I get following error:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/steph/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-29/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

The strange thing is: This used to still work last week. And I am on a MacBook Pro M1. When I run `arch` in the terminal I get "arm64".

Why does the emulator think I am on a x86_64 host?

Comment: having the same issue, were you able to solve that?

Comment: I solved it by uninstalling `android-sdk` (I was using the homebrew version, so I did `brew uninstall android-sdk --cask`) and getting it directly from the Android Studio homepage. This tutorial was pretty helpful https://bajtos.net/posts/2021-12-17-apple-m1-android-emulator/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling my whole Android Studio + SDK and reinstalling it again.